# $A\subseteq B\subseteq X\implies f(A)\subseteq f(B)$. Show that, in general, the inclusions are proper.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(Y)$. Then $A\subseteq B\subseteq X\implies f(A)\subseteq f(B)$. Show that, in general, the inclusions are proper.

The function $f:\mathcal P(X)\to\mathcal P(Y)$ is a set-valued function induced from a function $f:X\to Y$, where $\mathcal P(X)$ and $\mathcal P(Y)$ are the power sets of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

I dont understand this exercise (one of the first exercises of the *Real analysis* of Amann and Escher). If $f$ is a constant function then we have that the statement

$$A\subsetneq B\subsetneq X\implies f(A)\subsetneq f(B)$$

is not true because $f(A)=f(B)$. So, Im wrong in the interpretation of this problem? Can someone enlighten this question? Thank you in advance.

Comment: no idea what he means, in fact a  functionn$f$ satisfies $A\subset B \implies f(A)\subset f(B)$ if and only if it is injective

Comment: @CarryonSmiling it is supposed that this is general for any kind of functions, not only injective.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Even if $f$ is injective, that doesn't necessarily mean $A \subset B \implies f(A) \subset f(B)$. Take the example where $X = Y$ and $f(A) = \overline{A}$ where $\overline{A}$ is the complement of $A$. Notice that $\emptyset \subset X$ but $f(\emptyset) = X \not \subset \emptyset = f(X)$.

Comment: The sentence "$A\subseteq B\subseteq X\implies f(A)\subseteq f(B)$" is a hypothesis, or something to prove?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling, The implication also doesn't imply $f$ is injective. Consider $f: x \mapsto x^2$.Take $A = [0, \infty)$ and $B = (-\infty,\infty)$. $A \subset B \implies f(A) \subset f(B)$, but $f$ is not injective.

Comment: @secs it is something to prove.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{P}$ the power set? And what kind of function is $f$? Anyway, "in general the inclusions are proper" just means that it can happen that the inclusions are proper

Comment: @57Jimmy yes, it is the power set. I added relevant information that I forget to put in the first place, sorry.

Comment: @AOrtiz clearly I mean for every set $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @beguin I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling My apologies, my comment was before the OP clarified that $f$ is a set-valued function induced from the function $f : X \to Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it should be $f: X \to Y$, not ${\mathcal P}(X) \to {\mathcal P}(Y)$.  Then it is true that $A \subseteq B \implies f(A) \subseteq f(B)$, where $f(A)$ means $\{f(a) \;: \; a \in A\}$.

EDIT: Ah, the extra bit "The function $f:P(X) \to P(Y)$ is a set-valued function induced from a function $f:X \to Y$" makes it clear that my interpretation is the correct one.  This is exactly how a set-valued function on the power set is induced by a function from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: It is clearly stated that it hold for set-valued induced functions on the power sets. I added some info that I forget to put in the original question.

Comment: Yes, sorry by this. But, how to intepret about the inclusions are proper "in general"? To me, "in general" means that hold for all cases.

Comment: Yes, that's the source of the confusion.  The English language is somewhat ambiguous.  In mathematics, "in general" does not mean "in all cases", it means "in some cases".

Comment: ... and "some cases" means "at least one case".

Comment: I understand but it doesnt make sense if you have an $\subseteq$ statement because it includes any proper case. Im not english speaker but in all mathematical book that I have read "in general" means "all cases". This is my source of confusion. Anyway the book is originally written in german so it is possible that the translation to english is not completely accurate.

Comment: I should amend that.  "In general" can mean "in all cases" or "in some cases" or "in almost all cases", depending on context.  It should be interpreted in such a way that the statement is plausibly true but not trivial.